# Integral with $(-1)^t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

can you suggest some exercise online where integral have $(-1)^x$  function  like

$\int g(x) dx$ where $g(x) = (-1)^x h(x)$ or $g(x) = h((-1)^x,x)$

Comment: What is $(-1)^x$ ? It has no sense if $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: Or $(-1)^x$ has meaning, but complex values.  Then you would probably write $\exp(i \pi x)$ to be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know of any special sources dealing with these sorts of integrals, but I can show you how to integrate it...

First, recall that $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$
Thus, with $x=\pi$ we have $$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
Take $\ln$ on both sides to get
$$i\pi=\ln(-1)$$
and since $$a^x=e^{x\ln a}$$
We have that 
$$(-1)^x=e^{x\ln(-1)}=e^{i\pi x}=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)$$
Which is easily integrated.